# src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder does not show up in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

When generating a Cloud Endpoints project in Android Studio, the src/main/webapp folder containing the html does not show up in Android Studio. Is there a special way to get the src/main/webapp files to show up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Choose "Project" view instead of "Android" view -- webapp files are a server thing, but the Android view is meant for Android device apps.

Screenshot:

[image: Screen shot showing menu of how to set the view]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Studio don't you think? Because of Studio integration with AppEngine and Cloud Endpoints I'd expect to work it in a more obvious way. If you remember file names it's easy to open them, but otherwise you have to switch the views every time.